# Python tarfile gzipped file bigger than sum of source files

Tags: python, tarfile

I have a Python routine which archives file recordings into a GZipped tarball. The output file appears to be far larger than the source files, and I cannot work out why. As an example of the scale of the issue, 6GB of call recordings are generating an archive of 10GB.

There appear to be no errors in the script and the output .gz file is readable and appears OK apart from the huge size.

Excerpt from my script as follows:

```
# construct tar filename and open file
client_fileid = client_id + "_" + dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
tarname = tar_path + "/" + client_fileid + ".tar.gz"
print "Opening tar file %s " % (tarname), "\n"
try:
  tar = tarfile.open (tarname, "w:gz")
except:
  print "Error opening tar file: %s" % sys.exc_info()[0]

sql="""SELECT number, er.id, e.id, flow, filename, filesize, unread, er.cr_date, callerid,
length, callid, info, party FROM extension_recording er, extension e, client c
WHERE er.extension_id = e.id AND e.client_id = c.id AND c.parent_client_id = %s
AND DATE(er.cr_date) BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'""" % (client_id, start_date, end_date)

rows = cur.execute(sql)
recordings = cur.fetchall()

if rows == 0: sys.exit("No recordings for selected date range - exiting")

for recording in recordings:  # loop through recordings cursor
  try:
ext_len = len(str(recording[0]))
# add preceding zeroes if the ext no starts with 0 or 00
if ext_len == 2: extension_no = "0" + str(recording[0])
elif ext_len == 1: extension_no = "00" + str(recording[0])
else:     extension_no = str(recording[0])
filename = recording[4]
extended_no = client_id + "*%s" % (extension_no)
sourcedir = recording_path + "/" + extended_no
tardir = extended_no + "/" + filename
complete_name = sourcedir + "/" + filename
tar.add(complete_name, arcname=tardir)  # add to tar archive
  except:
print "Error '%s' writing to tar file %s" % (sys.exc_info()[1], csvfullfilename)
```

Comment: Compression is not a panacea and *can* indeed result in larger files, if the input is not compressible. Compression makes use of repetitions in the input to produce smaller output, but if such repetitions are missing describing the unique data requires more metadata than can be saved.

Comment: What type of file are the call recordings?

Comment: The call recordings may already be compressed or encrypted. Compressing a well-encrypted file results in larger flies. You could save some of the recordings to a file and then gzip them on the command line to see what happens.

Comment: @mipadi they are GSM 16 bit 8kHz WAVs, they are fairly small so perhaps the internal compression is rendering them unable to be compressed further.

Comment: @tdelaney they are definitely not encrypted. As a test, I downloaded one of the tar.gz files (6GB), extracted it (3.5GB) then zipped it (3.4GB). So it must be fairly compressed although ZIP does a far better job that GZip in this case.

Comment: Zip and gzip both use the same compression algorithm (zlib), although your zip tool may default to a higher compression setting. Can you display the contents of the tarball using the command line tar?

Comment: Okay, shots in the dark! ...but do you have multiple files in there? What does `gunzip targ.gz` (ending w/ an uncompressed tar archive) give you. I'd think that WAVs would compress like crazy but maybe converting to another format like flac or mp3 would do a better job at compressing (just don't send the result to Neil Young).